# How do I get the mail() function working from scratch in php 5.3?

Tags: php, function, email, php-5.3

I'm new to php world (actually not so much, but pretty much).

I make little block webs so I can test each feature I need. Right now I'm having trouble with the mail() function that comes with PHP, and I looked the solution up in many sites. I've searched here but nothing helped, every time I found some answer that seemed to work, a new problem poped up.

Let me explain my situation:

I started making some codes where I included HTML forms so I could get user info for the mail structure, the idea is to generate a kind of trace, wich the user triggers in a specific moment with some info already loaded. Later, i noticed that if I couldn't get through with de mail() problem I wouldn't get it to work. So I minimized my problem, and just wrote:

```
<?php
     mail($mail, $subject, $body);
?>
```

Well, you can imagine, as I didn't modify php.ini since installing xampp (which I haven't mentioned before) I got some SMTP and sendmail_path errors;
So I looked up here and got some instructions to configure php.ini. Then tried again and nothing, it didn't work out.

Tried with PEAR's Mail_mime, but it just made everything blurrier, with the NON-Static problems.

Hope you can help.

I edited the php.ini file so i got

```
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25
```

I am not getting any error message right now, I just don't get an email, I also did set the from header, I forgot to point that out. I set the From header, within the phph.ini file, and when it didn't work I edited it inside a new code's variable. A more detailed picture would look like this:

```
<?php
     $to = 'rojas.damian.brz@gmail.com';
     $headers = array("From"=>"rojas.damian.brz@gmail.com");
     $subject = 'This is the subject.';
     $body = 'Here is the message.';

     mail($mail, $subject, $body, $headers);
?>
```

That was one of the many trials.

Comment: If you expect us to help, you could provide the actual error messages you're getting. The purpose of your site and what you're trying to do in the big picture is pointless - we just want the error messages.

Comment: Are you using your local machine as the SMTP relay, or have you entered a valid SMTP server that doesn't have  problem with the relay?

Comment: As you said, "I didn't modify php.ini since installing xampp" so I guess you have installed on your local window machine and for that you need to make changes to your php.ini in which you need to provide SMTP server.

Comment: That isn't how to set headers. `"Header: Value\r\nAnotherHeader: Value"` - as a string, not via an array.

Comment: Kamal I did modify it later, but didn't work either.
Sorry ScottS I tried so many thing that I don't remember which one is used with the default header, as I said, I also tried with Mail_mime, and that one need an array input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send the `From` header. It maybe setup to fall back to a default address, but my hunch is that it's not. Of course, this mightn't be the problem.

`mail($mail, $subject, $body, $headers);`

The example `From` header would be `From: noreply@example.com`. Separate headers in the string with `\r\n`.

Comment: You don't need the `From` header to use `mail()`. In fact, you don't need headers at all to send mail.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php - Note:

When sending mail, the mail must contain a From header. This can be set with the additional_headers parameter, or a default can be set in php.ini.

Failing to do this will result in an error message similar to Warning: mail(): "sendmail_from" not set in php.ini or custom "From:" header missing. The From header sets also Return-Path under Windows.

Comment: edited up used from header within the mail function and also tried in the php.ini file